# Получение времени последней загрузки системы - Android shell

Tags: android, adb

Как в shell'е на Android получить время последней загрузки системы? На англоязычном стаке такой вопрос [был](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15342301), но ответа там нет.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135966/how-to-get-android-system-uptime-and-realtime-from-command-line

Comment: @zenden2k мне нужно именно время включения, а не аптайм

Comment: @Yalikesifulei, а в чём, по-вашему, заключается разница?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin всё, дошло. Не понял сначала. :)

Answer (score 1):

ответ с [англоязычного *so*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18136177/4827341):

попробуйте

```
$ adb shell cat /proc/uptime
```